# rename multiple files recursively and remove multiple characters such as ? : or newline from names

Tags: rename, filenames

I have seen a few similar questions, but nothing that shows how to remove any of a set of special characters from all file names recursively.

I want to keep uppercase and lowercase letters, numbers and underscores and get rid of all special characters in the filenames. I have seen colons and question mark chars and a couple file names with newlines.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do it from command-line , you can use rename command.

```
rename 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]//' *.<file_format>
```

The above command will retain Uppercase,lowercase letters ,underscore and numbers. It removes all other chars.

Comment: Thanks but that does not remove double quote chars from the file names. Also, you need to add `\.` so that it does not remove the dot before the file extension. Hope you can improve your answer.

Comment: also this doesn't handle subdirectories recursively.

Comment: @MountainX I have checked its man-page .It dont have such facility .

Comment: You'll want to use the `g` flag, like so: `'s/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]//g'`, otherwise this will only remove the *first* match for the pattern. I think that is the issue @MountainX is running into, since this command removes double quote characters for me perfectly well. I would also recommend looking up 'bash globstar' if you want recursiveness, MountainX.